# awk error while printing the fifth column of log file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to print the lines of log file based on 5th column value  But getting error at the end.

**script.sh**

```
num=0
str=" "
tail -n 10000 /var/temp.log | awk '$5=="[200]" {print}'
echo -n "Enter the first number --> "
read num
str="'\$5==\"[$num]\" {print}'"
echo This is the string for awk argument
echo $str
echo
tail -n 10000 /var/temp.log  | awk $str    
//getting error here
```

After running script.sh ==> ./script.sh

```
Prints the lines which are consisting [200] in the column 5 of log file. 
Enter the first number --> 100
This is the string for awk argument
'$5=="[100]" {print}'

awk: '$5=="[100]"
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

How do I fix this ?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the single quotes and use double quotes when expanding it:

```
str="\$5==\"[$num]\" {print}"

tail -n 10000 /var/temp.log  | awk "$str"
```

Comment: can you give brief on this? By seeing the result after echo $str ,the last command also needs works as required.

Comment: It's simply about how they are expanded. The command you wanted to pass to awk is in the format of `$5=="[200]" {print}`. You just have to choose your ways to store it on a variable and ways to expand it. If we add to the single quote literally to the value, it would be included in awk as well as `'$5=="[200]" {print}'` since the quote would no longer be a form of shell syntax and would cause syntax error to awk. `awk "$var"` would expand to something like `awk` `$5=="[200]" {print}` which is what you needed. Your echo command by the way needs to be quoted as well: `echo "$var"`.

Comment: For the sake of concept if we have a variable assignment like `A="'a b   c'"`, if we run it with `echo $A` the first thing that would happen is that it would be split into three arguments with IFS: `'a`, `b`, and `c'`. And the message would be `'a b c'`. Notice that the length of space is now only 1. If we do `echo "$A"` (quoted), it show the message as is: `'a b   c'`. This just means that a literal single quote value passed in an open expansion (with or without double-quotes) is not parsed as part of the shell syntax and is included as a whole with the other characters to the command.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dynamically building the awk program, you can pass the value into awk with the `-v` option:

```
read -p "enter a number: " num
awk -v n="[$num]" '$5==n {print}'
```

Also `{print}` is the default action when the condition is true, so you can omit it:

```
awk -v n="[$num]" '$5==n'
```

Comment: `read -p` ==> no need to use echo. `awk -v` avoid usage of `str`      Simple and Interesting.... thank you....

Answer (score 1):

You should quote the shell variable to prevent word splitting. Try with:

```
.... | awk "$str"
```

Also use either singe or double quotes, but not both:

```
str='$5=="['"$num"']" {print}'
```

Comment: That would still cause an error. See my answer. Using single quotes would also not let $num expand.